# Default Flexbox panel for keyboard scrolling

Tags: css, flexbox

Let's assume you have a website with a header, content area and footer created using Flexbox, as follows:

https://codepen.io/anthonyLukes/pen/DLBeE

The header sits at the top of the window, the footer sits at the bottom, and the content area fills the space in between. If the content is greater than the content div, then a scroll bar is shown just for that div.

Visually, this works a treat, but it does create a curious problem: keyboard scrolling no longer works.

As the page has no natural notion of primary content area, pressing page down, down arrow and end does nothing. To scroll the page with the keyboard, you must first click into the content div!

You can fix this with JavaScript (note that this ID is not set in the Codepen example):

```
document.getElementById("content").focus();
```

In addition, for Opera (and presumably Chrome) the content div must also have tabindex set (otherwise the above instruction does nothing).

Now, to me, this seems wrong. It would stand to reason that there should be a way to declaratively indicate which part of the page should initially be scrolled with page up/down, up/down and home/end without having to resort to JavaScript. Using Flexbox to achieve clean whole-page layout shouldn't break the user's very long-standing expectation that a page can be scrolled with the keyboard.

However, I can't find any suggestion that anyone else has ever noticed this issue. I found it almost immediately after implementing the above!

As a note, using `<!DOCTYPE HTML>` with `<header>`, `<main>` and `<footer>` has no effect either. Since Flexbox can be used for any part of a page, it seems not to be a straightforward issue: the browser must also understand that the Flexbox in question constitutes the whole page and should set scrolling!

Is there actually a way to indicate which flex panel should start out with keyboard focus?